# how to solve the last x value under the condition the linear regression equals to zero in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

assume that I have some data, and I can calculate the the slope with scipy.stats.linregress
for example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

data = np.array([1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -7, -8, 6, 11])
x = np.arange(len(data))
slope = stats.linregress(x, data)[:1]
```

As you can see , I can get the slope of the linear regression;
but I want to append a x value to the data to make the slope equals to zero
how I can solve this x ? thanks

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense. You need an `x` and a `y` to do linear regression. Any constraints on the intercept? BTW, this is more of a math question than a programming question.

Comment: Your example raises an error because you haven't provided `scipy.stats.linregress` with any y data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my math for slope from here - https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/probability-and-statistics/regression-analysis/find-a-linear-regression-equation/#FindaLinear

Assuming, you intended the following:

```
import numpy as np
from spicy import stats
y = np.array([1,2,3,-1,-2,-7,-8,6,11])
x = np.array(range(0,len(y)))
slope = stats.linregress(x,y).slope
```

And to the set up above, you want to append a value to `y` and revise `x` to be the new `np.array(range(0,len(y)))`, such that the new slope for the regression will be equal to `0`. Then the math is actually quite simple to compute the additional number you are appending to `y`.

Use the equation for the slope (`b`) provided in the link above and do the following:

1. replace `n` with `(n+1)`
2. add `(n+1)` to `sum(x)`
3. add the unknown variable `i` to `sum(y)`
4. add `(n+1)i` to `sum(x*y)`

Once you do that, solve the equation for `i` and you will get the equation you need to compute the value. Here it is in action:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np 
   ...: from scipy import stats                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [2]: y = data = np.array([1,2,3,-1,-2,-7,-8,6,11])

In [3]: x = np.array(range(0,len(data)))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

In [4]: n = len(data)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

In [5]: slope = stats.linregress(x,y).slope                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

In [6]: slope                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[6]: 0.4

In [11]: def append_computer(x,y): 
...:     n = len(x) 
...:     m = n+1 
...:     if ((m**2) - sum(x) - m) > 0: 
...:         num = (-1*m*(sum(x*y))+(sum(x)*sum(y))+m*sum(y))/((m**2) - sum(x) - m) 
...:         return num 
...:     else: 
...:         raise ValueError(f"Solution not possible")

In [12]: stats.linregress(np.append(x,n+1), np.append(y,append_computer(x,y))).slope                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[12]: 0.0
```

Comment: wow~~~@Aryan Jain  awesome!  the formula in the link  is exact what i want to find
thanks